# HTML Print multiple documents with one dialog

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I'm working on bringing a website up to current standards and removing frames.  We have a page for printing multiple documents.  When you load the page, it prints all the documents individually, but only asks you to pick your printer once.  Here is a simplified version of the code (tested, working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print test</title>

    <script>
        function printAll() {
            printAllForms.focus();
            if (window.print) {
                window.print();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <frameset rows="20%,*" id="printAllForms" onload="printAll()">
        <frame id="form1" src="page1.html">
        <frame id="form2" src="page2.html">
        <noframes>You need the frames</noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I was thinking it might be better to use iFrames.  Based on other similar questions, I came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print test</title>

    <script>
        function printPage() {
            for (var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; k++) {
                window.frames[k].focus();
                window.frames[k].print();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="form1" src="page1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="form2" src="page2.html"></iframe>

    <button id="btnPrint" onclick="printPage()">Print</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, BUT it shows a dialog every time.

Another method I'm working on is to load DIVs with the data.  It will print all as one document.  This can be an issue if the user is printing double sided and there is a document with an odd number of pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: Aren't you always at the mercy of the user's individual print settings?

Comment: @ScottMarcus  My main concerns are 1 dialog, vs multiple dialogs and multiple documents vs 1 document.  This should be sorted out before it gets to the users settings. It works the way I want with the frames, but I want to get rid of the frames.